# do not print duplicate entries from php array

Tags: php, sql

Trying not to print duplicate values from a field in my table.[image]

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

```
// fetches a result row as an assosiative array
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>";

          echo "<td>" . $row["first_name"] . "</td>";

          echo "<td>" . $row["last_name"] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row["book_id_fk"] . "</td>";

          echo "<td>" . $row["quantity"] . "</td>";

          echo "<td>" . $row["grade"] . "</td>";
      ;


}
```

i tried using array_unique function 
echo "" . array_unique( $row["student_id_fk"]) . "";

but my error message is

**array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given**

Can anyone help me with this. How do I pass in the array and not a string?

Comment: Looks like you are doing it wrong. The duplicate rows should probably be filtered out at the SQL level.

Comment: Instead of using `array_unique()`, why not do it straight in the query? If you want unique records, you can use DISTINCT and/or GROUP BY.